# How to Implement Two Dimensional 'Map' in Console in C Language

Tags: c, indexing

I'm doing some project in data structure class in my school.
I wanted to implement some 'lands' in console, so I tried hard as below.

First I drew what I want to execute in excel and check which indexes I should allocate lines to.

[image]

And I stored each indexes in two dimensional arrays.

```
int NODE[5][NUM] =
{
    {0},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,31,37,61,67,91,97, 121,122,123,124,125,126,127}
    {15,16,17,18,19,20,21,45,51,75,81,105,111,135,136,137,138,139,140,141},
    {301,302,303,304,305,306,307,331,337,361,367,391,397,421,422,423,424,425,426,427},
    {315,316,317,318,319,320,321,345,351,375,381,405,411,435,436,437,438,439,440,441}
};
```

And in the two dimensional map array,
First I allocate space characters in all indexes,
Second I allocate CR('\n') charactes in each end of the row,
Third I allocate '#' as a edge of the land using NODE array above.

I used pointer casting to approach the two dimensional array as index.

```
int* ptr = (int*)map;

void map_initialize()
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 30; j++)
            map[i][j] = 32;

    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < NUM; j++)
            ptr[NODE[i][j]] = '#';

    for (i = 29; i < 450; i += 30)
        ptr[i] = '\n';

}
```

I thought my plan was perfect but the result was desperate.

[image]

I don't know where I did wrong. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: My guess: Your executing it on Windows command line. Thus, `CR` only is not enough, you need to add `LF` in the `30` ( or `CR` in `28` and `LF` in `29`) cells to get a correct visualisation.

Comment: You don't show the code that displays the map, so it's hard to tell what you did wrong. You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: I would use an internal two-dimensional buffer of chars and draw into this. Then you can draw parts of that internal buffer on the console. This way you can rely on your internal structure when drawing and delegate formatting issues to the console renderer. If you later want to draw into a grafical window you need to rewrite the renderer, only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First potential problem:**

If you declared your map as follow as a two dimensional array:

```
char map[15][30];
```

Then, when you want to use it as a one-dimention array, you should cast it that way:

```
char* ptr = (char*)map;
```

Because if you have got an array of characters and you cast it as an array of `int`, every index pointed by `ptr` skips four indexes from your map

**Second potential problem:**

Your array `NODE` doesn't have all lines with the same length, which makes it mostly unmanageable, unless you're using a "terminating character" for each line.

**If I try and write something to fix the two issues above, I get:**

```
#include "stdio.h"


int Node0[]={0, -1};
int Node1[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,31,37,61,67,91,97, 121,122,123,124,125,126,127, -1};
int Node2[]={15,16,17,18,19,20,21,45,51,75,81,105,111,135,136,137,138,139,140,141, -1};
int Node3[]={301,302,303,304,305,306,307,331,337,361,367,391,397,421,422,423,424,425,426,427, -1};
int Node4[]={315,316,317,318,319,320,321,345,351,375,381,405,411,435,436,437,438,439,440,441, -1};

int *NODE[5]=
{
    Node0,
    Node1,
    Node2,
    Node3,
    Node4
};

char perNode[5]= { ' ', '#', '#', '@', '@'};

char map[15][30];
char* ptr = (char*)map;

void map_initialize()
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 30; j++)
            map[i][j] = ' ';

    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        for (j = 0; NODE[i][j] != -1 ; j++)
            ptr[NODE[i][j]] = perNode[i] ;

    for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
        map[i][29] = '\n';
}

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    int i ;
    map_initialize();
    for (i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++)
        printf("%.30s", map[i]);
}
```

This program generates the following output:

```
 #######       #######       
 #     #       #     #       
 #     #       #     #       
 #     #       #     #       
 #######       #######       
                             
                             
                             
                             
                             
 @@@@@@@       @@@@@@@       
 @     @       @     @       
 @     @       @     @       
 @     @       @     @       
 @@@@@@@       @@@@@@@
```